# Set many value for one Atrribut java to add on list filtred

Tags: java, java-8

im using java8 , and i wanna to set many value for adding to a list, i make this code and it worked, but i think they are a thing much better.

```
private String value;
public List<Entity> finalList;
public List<Entity> getList() {

        value= "AB";
        List<Entity> list2;
        List<Entity> list3;

        finalList= EntityService.filtermethod(value);
        list2= EntityService.filtermethod("BC");
        for (Entity val : list2) {
            finalList.add(val);

        }
        list3= EntityService.filtermethod("CD");
        for (Reservation val : list3) {
            finalList.add(reser);

        }

        return finalList;
    }
```

thank you all

Comment: This is uncompilable. What `EntityService::filtermethod` returns? How `list1` should even be treated (you return as is regardless the method body).

Comment: EntityService::filtermethod is Jpa method , filtermethod(String etat)

Comment: what exactly do you want to do? does this what you want: ´finalList.addAll(EntityService.filtermethod("...")); finalList.addAll(EntityService.filtermethode("---")); .... return finalList´

Answer (score 1):

> I make this code and it worked, but I think they are things much better.

Yes! There are thousands of ways to make the code better but please consider to learn basic things,

- Learn to use [variables](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) and [access-modifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/accesscontrol.html)
- If `EntityService.filtermethod()` is not null-safe, consider checking null before adding them(otherwise you need to face [NullPointerException](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/NullPointerException.html)), one of a good way is using [Optional](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

I have shrunk your method `getList()`,

```
public List<Entity> getList() {
    return Stream.of(
            EntityService.filtermethod("AB"),
            EntityService.filtermethod("BC"),
            EntityService.filtermethod("CD")
        )
        .flatMap(Collection::stream)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```